# Bar plot in seaborn

Tags: seaborn, bar-chart, eda

While doing EDA of [Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic) in Kaggle I combined "Parch" and "SibSp" values into single feature "relative" containing total no of relatives of each passenger.

```
data['relative'] = data['Parch'] + data['SibSp']
```

On plotting barplot **relatives** vs **Survived** using Seaborn I have got following output

[image: Bar plot]

**Query**

I can't understand this barplot as
Survived feature in this dataset has only two values **1 and 0** and relative also has **6 values ranging from 1 to 6** so how this barplot is generated  and What information it is showing?

Comment: Hint: [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) has an `estimator` parameter.

Comment: Got it thanks.
On executing train.groupby("relatives")["Survived"].mean()
Same values are plotted in bar plot

Comment: In this case it would probably be better to do `sns.countplot(data=data, x='survived', hue='relatives')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `seaborn.barplot` documentation.

> help(seaborn.barplot)

The plot is showing you the mean of the 'Survived' values per bin ('N of relatives'). You could specify the `estimator` parameter to change this behaviour (e.g. `estimator=median`).

> A bar plot represents an estimate of central tendency for a numeric
> variable with the height of each rectangle and provides some
> indication of the uncertainty around that estimate using error bars.
> Bar plots include 0 in the quantitative axis range, and they are a
> good choice when 0 is a meaningful value for the quantitative
> variable, and you want to make comparisons against it.